# Customise hover location on image map menu in JQuery tooltipster

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

[image: This is how I would like the hover to work]
This is how I would like the hover to work.

I'm trying to re-position the text when the user is hovering over the image map menu, so that they are all be unanimous and appear centered above the image.

I have been unable to re-position them as they individually react differently when I add the CSS.

Ideally, I would like to have the hover box in the borderless theme in black so only the text appears in white above the image map when the users hovers between menu items.

Thanks in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
    theme: ['tooltipster-noir', 'tooltipster-noir-customized']
  });
});
```

```css
.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-noir.tooltipster-noir-customized .tooltipster-box {
  background: black;
  Border: 0;
}

.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-noir.tooltipster-noir-customized .tooltipster-content {
  color: white;
  font-family: "josefin sans";
  font-size: 3rem;
  Border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/dist/js/tooltipster.bundle.js"></script>
<link href="http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/dist/css/tooltipster.bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRo8A.png" id="logo" style="width: 260px; max-width: 100%; height: auto;" alt="" usemap="#map" />

<map name="map">
  <area shape="circle" coords="243,132,41" href="Konpakutotrack.html" class="tooltip" title="Track" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="189,223,41" alt='' href="Konpakutoinsurance.html"  class="tooltip" title="Insurance Cov."/>
  <area shape="circle" coords="69,205,29" alt='' href='Konpakutohealth.html' class="tooltip" title="Health"/>
  <area shape="circle" coords="9,131,42" alt='' href='Konpakutounlocklock.html'  class="tooltip" title="Lock" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="128,49,81" alt='' href='index.html' class="tooltip" title="Home" />
</map>
```

Comment: Can you have a text area that's static, and then the hover event instead of showing a tool tip can change text and visibility of the text area?